# Assign VAL of input to other inputs before the click method

Tags: jquery

I have 3 date range forms on my site.  Essentially I want to hide two of the date ranges and only show the user one.  However, I still need the value's chosen in the one date range to be distributed to the other date ranges.  I tried applying the VAL of the first date range to a variable before click and applying it to the other inputs, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('#edit-submit-calendar-full').click(function(){
                var startDate = $('#edit-fd-min-datepicker-popup-1').val();
                var endDate = $('#edit-fd-max-datepicker-popup-1').val();

                $('#edit-fw-min-datepicker-popup-1').val(startDate);
                $('#edit-fw-min-datepicker-popup-1').val(endDate);

                $('#edit-sd-min-datepicker-popup-1').val(startDate);
                $('#edit-sd-min-datepicker-popup-1').val(endDate);
            });
```

EDIT:  This does seem to be working for this basic example, but when it redirects to another page, the inputs never get filled in.  Doing some more testing.

Comment: What's not working? can you reproduce the "not working" at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It works for me here : http://jsfiddle.net/8G8BY/. An example of a nonworking one would be helpful.

Comment: what gets redirected to the other page? some fiddle please..

Comment: I can't fiddle it, it's on a Drupal site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an error with my selectors.  The code above works properly.